# how to query data limit in one type using nest elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

in NEST 2.x, I wrote code to query data like below:

```
var query = new QueryContainer();
query = query && new TermQuery { Field = "catId", Value = catId };
query = query && new NumericRangeQuery { Field ="price", GreaterThan = 10 };

var request =new SearchRequest<Project>
{
    From = 0,
    Size = 100,
    Query = query,
    Sort = new List<ISort>
            {
                new SortField { Field = "field", Order = SortOrder.Descending },
                ...
            },
    Type?? //problem comes here, how to specify type??
}

var response = _client.Search<Project>(request);
```

There are more than one type in my index, I want to query data in one of type.(just like query one of table data in a database), I hope in the SearchRequest object initializer have a "Type" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the [indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/indices-paths.html) and types in the constructor for `SearchRequest<T>()`

```
var catId = 1;

var query = new QueryContainer(new TermQuery { Field = "catId", Value = catId });
query = query && new NumericRangeQuery { Field = "price", GreaterThan = 10 };

var request = new SearchRequest<Project>("index-name", Types.Type(typeof(Project), typeof(AnotherProject)))
{
    From = 0,
    Size = 100,
    Query = query,
    Sort = new List<ISort>
        {
            new SortField { Field = "field", Order = Nest.SortOrder.Descending },
        }
};

var response = client.Search<Project>(request);
```

would generate the following query

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index-name/project%2Canotherproject/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "field": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "catId": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gt": 10.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```